# Эмуляция нажатия мыши в другом окне в бэкграунде

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Никак не выходит эмулировать клик мыши в бэкграунд окне, пробовал Post(Send)Message но без результатно, окно эти события видит, но реакции нет. И события клика 'нормальной' мышью окном интерпретируются несколько по иному, ниже лог поведения с обычной мышью.

```
  <000046> 000102C0 S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:00010302 nHittest:HTCLIENT wMouseMsg:WM_MOUSEMOVE
  <000047> 000102C0 R WM_SETCURSOR fHaltProcessing:False
  <000048> 000102C0 S WM_PARENTNOTIFY fwEvent:WM_LBUTTONDOWN xPos:20 yPos:303
  <000049> 000102C0 R WM_PARENTNOTIFY
  <000050> 000102C0 S WM_MOUSEACTIVATE hwndTopLevel:000102C0 nHittest:HTCLIENT uMsg:WM_LBUTTONDOWN
  <000051> 000102C0 R WM_MOUSEACTIVATE fuActivate:MA_ACTIVATE
  <000052> 000102C0 S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:00010302 nHittest:HTCLIENT wMouseMsg:WM_LBUTTONDOWN
  <000053> 000102C0 R WM_SETCURSOR fHaltProcessing:False
```

Событие WM_PARENTNOTIFY емулировать не удается, окно не видит его, я так понимаю что это событие должна организовывать сама система, или я заблуждаюсь?

С SendInput конечно работает, но для этого надо доставать окно на передний план, что не есть хорошо.
Как бы организовать клик мыши в бекграунд окне?

Comment: Как можно выполнить клик мыши в фоновом окне, если клик мыши по определению поднимает окно наверх?

Comment: А ведь можно же, тому масса примеров ботов и прочих варезов. В конце концов все сводится к отсылке верного дампа сообщений системе - эмуляция живой мыши. С функцией PostMessage работает кстати и в бекграунде с нотепадом, при последующем переключении на него имеем курсор на нужной позиции.

Comment: Нормальные приложения игнорируют события ввода, если они не находятся в фокусе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А ларчик то просто открывался, для реализации щелчка мыши в окне на заднем плане, надо сперва послать `WM_SETFOCUS` а по окончании клика `WM_KILLFOCUS` :) и не мигает окнами как исчадие ада `SendInput` :)
До клика надо ещё послать `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE`.
Хинт в том, что окно думает что к нему пришел долгожданный фокус, и реагирует на мышинные телодвижения.

P.S. клик надо посылать целевому суб окну, а не главному, если их больше одного.